# Prove $\frac{\sin(x)}{x}$ is decreasing over $[0,\pi/2]$

Tags: calculus, analysis

How do I prove that $\sin(x)/x$ is a decreasing function on $[0,\pi/2]$? I tried taking the derivative and proving that's it's negative but I can't get to any nice inequalities.

Comment: What did you find as the derivative? If your result is correct, you get an inequality that is not immediately obvious, but after a little rearranging not difficult to show.

Comment: the derivative was Cos(x)/x-Sin(x)/x^2.

Comment: Right. If you write that as a single fraction, you see that you want to prove $x\cos x \leqslant \sin x$ for $x \in [0,\pi/2]$. That is equivalent to $x \leqslant \tan x$ there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$(\sin(x)/x)' 
= (x \cos(x) - \sin(x))/x^2
= \cos(x)(x - \tan(x))/x^2
$

so this is equivalent to
$\tan(x) > x
$
for
$0 < x < \pi/2$.

Answer (score 5):

Use the expression below,
$$ f(x)= \frac{\sin(x)}{x}=\int_0^1 \cos(xt)dt$$

Then, take the derivetive,

$$ f’(x) = -\int_0^1 t \sin(xt)dt\lt 0$$

The above inequality holds for $x = (0,\pi/2]$.
Thus, $f(x)$ is decreasing.

Comment: According to your answer isn’t $f(x)$ decreasing in $(\infty, \infty)$? But when you draw the function it decreases in certain intervals only

Comment: Note that $f’(x)$ is negative only for some $x$, not all $x$.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $\tan x \geq x$ in $(0,\pi/2)$ because $\frac d {dx} (\tan x -x)=\sec^{2}x-1 >0$ in $(0,\pi/2)$. Now compute the derivative of $\frac {\sin x} x$ and show that this derivative is negative in $(0,\pi/2)$. Now finish the proof using continuity.